# .empty() not working when user types too fast

Tags: javascript, jquery

Created [this](http://www.fbstatussearch.com/) website. Works fine if characters in the search box are entered slowly(5 results get displayed) but when typed fast, multiple of 5 results get displayed, indicating that `.empty()` does not work. Please guide.

Document Ready,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#search").keyup(function(e){
$("#status").empty();
/*
var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

if(keyCode == 13) {*/
myFunction();
//}
});
$("#status").hide();
$("#more").hide(); 
});
</script>
```

Some more JS added,
        
    var nexturl ="";
    var lastid ="";
    var param;

```
function myFunction() {
    param = $('#search').val();
    //alert("I am an alert box!");
    if (param != "") {
        $("#status").show();
        //alert("Show ");
        var u = 'https://graph.facebook.com/search/?callback=&limit=5&q='+param;
        $("#data").empty();     //empty the data div
        //alert("emptied?");
        getResults(u);
        $("#more").show(); 
        }

    $("#more").click(function () { 
    $("#status").show();
    //alert("Show ");
    $("#more").hide();  
    pageTracker._trackPageview('/?q=/more');
    var u = nexturl;
    getResults(u);
  });
}
</script>
```

The HTML involved,

```
<div style="margin-bottom:10px;float:right;">
        <form action="" method="get" id="searchform" onsubmit="return false;">
        <input name="q" type="text" id="search" onClick="this.select();" size="32" maxlength="128" class="txt"  style="padding: 0 5px;" >
        <input type="button" id="hit" value="Search" onclick="myFunction();return false" class="btn">
        </form>
</div>
</div>
<div id="data_container">
<div id="data">
    <div id="status_container">
  <div id="status"><img src="loader.gif" alt="loading facebook status search"/></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

The getResults() function,

```
function getResults(u) {
//$("#status").show();  
$("#data").empty();                                                 // print that we are in
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "jsonp", 
        url: u,
        success: function(res) {                                                        // take an object res
                $("#data").empty(); 
              $("#status").show();                                                      // show status
              $("#more").show();    
              if (res.data.length) {                                                    // check length of res
                                                                    // print if >0
                nexturl = res.paging.next;                                              // calculate next url
                  $.each(res.data, function(i,item){
                    if (item.id != lastid) {
                        lastid = item.id;
                        var html ="<div class=\"post\">";

                        html += "<div class=\"message\"><a href=\"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/profile.php?id="+item.from.id+"\">"+item.from.name+"</a> ";

                        if (item.message) { 
                            html += item.message+"<\/div>";
                        } else {
                            html += "<\/div>";
                        }
                        if (item.picture) { 
                            html += "<div class=\"image\"><img src=\""+item.picture+"\"></div>";
                        } else {
                            html += "<div class=\"image\"><\/div>";
                        };
                        if (item.link) { 
                            html += "<div class=\"link\"><a href=\""+item.link+"\">"+item.name+"</a></div>";

                            if (item.caption) { 
                                    html += "<div class=\"caption\">"+item.caption+"</div>";
                            };
                            if (item.description) { 
                                    html += "<div class=\"description\">"+item.description+"</div>";
                            };

                        };

                        html += "<div class=\"meta\">";

                        if (item.icon) { 
                            html += "<span class=\"icon\"><img src=\""+item.icon+"\"></span> ";
                        };
                        var t = item.created_time;
                        var time = t.substring(0,19)+"\+00:00";
                        html += "<span class=\"time\">"+$.cuteTime({},time)+"<\/span> ";
                        html += " <\/div>";

                        html +="</div>";
                        $("#data").append(html) ;
                    }
                  });
                    $("#more").appendTo("#data");
                    $("#more").show();
                    $("#status").appendTo("#data");


            } else {
                $("#data").append("<h3 class=\"none\">No entries found. Please try another search.</h3>");
            }; 
        } 

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chrome and FireFox it does work for me.  It just continues changing with every character and catches up - which is typical.  It might be a good idea to add a short delay in between result changing, though, so that you can better track and watch the changes for testing purposes or report out to the console when the .empty() fires and what that selector's contents are after to ensure it does work the way you expect it.

Comment: The .empty() function gets triggered whenever I type in a character but but it does the clear the div. Have a look again

Comment: You can use something like $(".element").html(""); as well with, perhaps, better results.

Comment: I just added 500ms delay to call the function and it works fine now. Thanks for the advice. Still. I will be looking for a logical reason why this was needed.

Comment: When you call something, it queues, but can be visually/effectively overwritten by the next call and/or just not seen because the refill happened too quickly.  You see that a lot in navigation dropdowns when a .stop() is not called - too many fast movements and it goes haywire.